# Closed form of A Log-Sine-Cosine Integral by Mathematica

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form, mathematica

By using the Mathematica 12.0, I found the numerical value of a Log-Sine-Cosine Integral that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \log^2(2\sin\theta)\log(\tan(\theta/2))d\theta=-4.39530911884935704937076725879.$$
On the other hand, we have
$$-\frac{40}{9}\beta(4)=-\frac{40}{9}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^4}=-4.39530911884935704937076725879.$$
Hence, the following equation seems to be correct
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \log^2(2\sin\theta)\log(\tan(\theta/2))d\theta=-\frac{40}{9}\beta(4) ?$$
But how to prove it?

Comment: Just a detail : $$-\frac{40}{9}\beta(4)=\frac{5}{288} \left(\zeta \left(4,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta
   \left(4,\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \beta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^1 \dfrac{(-\ln x)^{s-1}}{1+x^2}dx$

Comment: Using PARI GP: ? \p 200
bet(s)={intnum(x=0,1,(-log(x))^(s-1)/(1+x^2))*1/gamma(s)}
A=intnum(x=0,Pi/6,log(2*sin(x))^2*log(tan(x/2)))
lindep([A,bet(4)])
   realprecision = 202 significant digits (200 digits displayed)
%3 = [9, 40]~